# What is a "progress event" error in HttpRequest of Dart?

Tags: dart, httprequest

I wanted to get String from "https://google.com" using HttpRequest.getString() method. I used asynchronous way for this.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async{
  try{
    print(await HttpRequest.getString("https://google.com"));
  }catch(e){
    print(e);
  }
}
```

But I got a error message "Instance of ProgressEvent". I know what is "Instance of Future" but what is this?